# Monitoring Orion Context Broker to create new XACML rules

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, xacml, abac, authzforce

I would like to know if is possible achieve this work environment:

I'm building a secure Orion Context Broker through PEP, PDP, PAP, etc.
I would like that, in case of Orion stores an abnormal value for an attribute, an alert was sent (an email, e.g) and, a new XACML rule was created so a role-user can see those values (before this happens he doesn't have to have permission to see it).

Is it possible? If it is, how can I achieve it?
Is there any option to do it through jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in case of Orion stores an abnormal value for an attribute, an alert was sent ( e.g an email)

The FIWARE component to use to send an eMail in this case would be **Complex Event Processing**  - e.g.  [Perseo](https://github.com/telefonicaid/perseo-core)

You can set up an EPL rule to send an eMail

> Set up an XACML rule to only allow access if an attribute is *"abnormal"*

This looks like a standard `<Condition>` clause, for example, the following:

```xml
<Condition>
   <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:time-greater-than-or-equal">
      <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:time-one-and-only">
         <EnvironmentAttributeSelector DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#time"
           AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:current-time"/>
      </Apply>
      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#time">17:00:00</AttributeValue>
   </Apply>
</Condition>
```

will only allow an action after a certain time of day.

I guess you may be looking at using `"urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:double-greater-than"` or `urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:integer-greater-than"` in the `<Condition>` something like:

```xml
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:integer-greater-than-or-equal">
   <SubjectAttributeDesignator SubjectCategory="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subjectcategory:accesssubject" AttributeId="SubjectClassificationRank" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer" MustBePresent="false"></SubjectAttributeDesignator>
   <ResourceAttributeDesignator AttributeId="ResourceClassificationRank" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer" MustBePresent="false"></ResourceAttributeDesignator>
</Apply>
```

Now here is the tricky bit, you will need to amend the code of your PEP proxy to ensure you can pass the the value of the *"abnormal"* attribute so that Authzforce can adjudicate.

The logic will need to be something like this:

1. Whenever the **PEP Proxy** is invoked, within the **PEP Proxy** make a direct call to Orion to retrieve the *current* attribute value.
2. Within your [PEP Proxy](https://github.com/ging/fiware-pep-proxy/blob/master/lib/azf.js#L96) amend the XML creation function to add the relevant attribute.
3. Call Authzforce to check if the request is permitted

The point here is that the standard code of the **PEP Proxy** won't have the necessary information to allow **Authzforce** to adjudicate, so you're going to have to add in more information.

A simpler scenario of the same type occurs within the following [Tutorial](https://github.com/Fiware/tutorials.Administrating-XACML) - here the User's eMail address is added to the request to **Authzforce**, you'll just have to apply the same principle.